# How to drop the word "ball" in 1000 columns except "K9- ball" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, dataframe, scikit-learn

This one might be a bit different than the regular expressions already on StackOverflow. I hope this question is not a duplicate.

I have 1000 columns of which 400 contain the word "ball". Such as "a - ball", "b-ball", "ball - c". The word ball can appear anywhere in the column order. The code I use is

```
 df.index.str.contains(K9\s|"ball")
```

The above regular expression drops all the columns containing "ball" and anything with K9 and whatever comes after K11, such as k11 - tennis.

My question is in the second part of the expression, I want to drop all the columns containing ball except the columns that have "K15 - balls".

Comment: What is `m1`? We're missing some context here.

Comment: Check `m1.index.str.contains("R15")` and add the needed logic.

Comment: Regex is evil, dont't ever use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not allowed to comment, have too low reputation.
I immediately overthunk this problem: are there many rows in these columns? In that case there would be a "rule precedence constraint" (?) since a single column would contain R14 (delete) and R15 (don't delete) on different rows.
If not, I would change "R15 - balls" to something else, delete as above, and then change it back.